# SQL Server trigger in value comparison: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table where I want to have a trigger on update action:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[cmt_update]
ON [dbo].[comments] 
FOR UPDATE
AS 
    DECLARE @Cinfo VARBINARY(128) 

    SELECT @Cinfo = Context_Info() 

    IF @Cinfo = 0x55555 
        RETURN 

    -- insert into syncro requests
    INSERT INTO syncros_requests (db_table_name, db_table_id,  action_type, request_date, syncro_status, syncro_msg, creation_date, usr,  edition_date, usr_edition)  
        SELECT 
            'comments', id, 'U', GETDATE(), 'NS', '', GETDATE(), usr, GETDATE(), usr 
        FROM 
            inserted

    IF (select pendent from deleted) = 0 AND (select pendent from inserted) = 1
    -- insert into syncro requests
    insert into syncros_requests(db_table_name, db_table_id,  action_type, request_date, syncro_status, syncro_msg, creation_date, usr,  edition_date, usr_edition)  
    select 'comments', id,  'D', GETDATE(), 'NS', '', GETDATE(), usr, GETDATE(), usr from inserted
```

The problem is when I update multiple rows at once, it gives the following error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure cmt_update, Line 17 [Batch Start
>   Line 8]
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

This error refers to this line:

```
IF (select pendent from deleted) = 0 AND (select pendent from inserted) = 1
```

While searching I've found that SQL Server trigger is executed by statement and not by row, causing this error only when I update multiple rows.

I have tried multiple solutions like this one but they didn't worked:

```
IF (select pendent from comments c inner join deleted d on d.id = c.id) = 0 AND (select pendent from comments c inner join inserted i on i.id = c.id) = 1
```

None of the solutions that I found where like my example, because trigger only breaks when I compare the values, because the code of both inserts are with the correct syntax.

I've found that using cursors may help but I'm not managing to make code right to work with it, can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: `(select pendent from deleted) = 0` and `(select pendent from inserted) = 1`; what if you `UPDATE` more than 1 row?

Comment: That's the point. The code breaks there because I found out that SQL Server trigger is statement-level and not row-level. I wrote the trigger like it was row-level and I want to know how to achieve the same result in statement-level when we update more that 1 row

Comment: *"I wrote the trigger like it was row-level"* and that's the problem, a trigger is "fired" once per DML statement, not once per row affected by a DML statement. Without really knowing what you're trying to achieve here, however, this is difficult to guess at. We have no sample data, no DDL of the other objects involved, or the expected behaviour results. My guess is you need an `INSERT` with a `WHERE`, not an `INSERT` preceded by an `IF`.

Comment: The table has a column named pendent. When this column is changed from 0 to 1 I want to dispult the second INSERT statement

Comment: "dispult"? What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry, bad translation this word doesn't exist in english. I meant "execute"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stab in the dark but...:

```
INSERT INTO syncros_requests (db_table_name,db_table_id,action_type,request_date,syncro_status,syncro_msg,creation_date,usr,edition_date,usr_edition)
SELECT 'comments',
       i.id,
       'D',
       GETDATE(),
       'NS',
       '',
       GETDATE(),
       i.usr,
       GETDATE(),
       i.usr
FROM inserted i
     JOIN deleted d ON i.YourIDColumn = d.YourIdColumn
WHERE i.pendent = 1
  AND d.pendent = 0;
```

Comment: Yes! That's exaclty what I wanted! I really appreciate your effort on understanding the problem and helping me to find a solution for my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

error is hare: `IF (select pendent from deleted) = 0 AND (select pendent from inserted) = 1`
you need to use like `IF exists(select pendent from deleted where pendent = 0) AND (select pendent from deleted where pendent = 0)

Keep enjoying...

Comment: This is very unlikely to give the desired result; the OP is checking if the value has been changed from `0` to `1` for `pendent`. If none of the rows had the value for `pendent` changed, but *at least* 1 has a value `1` and at least one the value `0` it would `INSERT` **all** the rows effected by the DML statement, even though none should be.